# correct way to automate department's reporting?

Tags: mysql, reporting, excel-2010, analytics

I just recently started my first job doing reporting and analytical on a project team. Currently a lot of data and reports are sitting in excel spreadsheets and in some database tables. Reports are drawn from this data in a very manual adhoc approach. It would seem that this has/is quickly becoming very problematic as the reporting requirements are increasing rapidly.  The project will soon be rolled out more quickly, and our manual efforts won't suffice.  Currently we are spending a lot of time manually doing etl like activities, the results are then sliced and diced in excel, and graphs and tables exported for management. After which the process has to be repeated for the next reporting cycle. We need to implement some automation in this regard.

As this is only a medium term project a full blown etl and reporting solution seems out of the question- neither time nor resources permits. Being a fresh graduate I know what has to be done, i just don't know what tools, utilities and software to implement. Google is just confusing me more. Any suggestions? Really feeling like I'm in over my head.

Comment: i think that you need a datawarehouse system and business inteligence.. IBM, Microsoft, etc have system for it..

Comment: @DanielRobertus. Thanks for the response. Yes I do agree  - in the end the correct infrastructure has to be provided by our IT department. However, our enterprise warehouse isn't at that maturity level yet. Nor does IT have the business insight to structure and clean the data correctly. Ideally, our reporting tools needed in the long term will be reimplemented by the warehouse team. However, I need to implement some departmental infrastructure to manage our reporting needs now.

Comment: if your datasource it can be done by querying tables and export it to excel manually. But if not its quite tricky if you not from IT background cause you need copy all the files you need to 1 place then you can start query.

Answer (score 1):

If number of Excel files are in tens rather than hundreds, I would suggest importing them to Access manually, and/or with bit of `VBA` standardise the data before importing.

Then, you can use Access to make reports.

Essentially, answer to your question boils down to this: [Is It Worth the Time](http://xkcd.com/1205/)?

Comment: One of the auditors are working with access on his side. I'll be looking into this as a possible solution. Nice link - thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you really need at least a reporting tool for automate this job, a tool that really covers most of what you need it's [DBxtra](http://dbxtra.com/), it connects directly to MySQL, exports to Excel and it can send the exported results (or a pretty designed report) to anyone by email automatically (for example every Monday at 6:00 AM), the biggest problem is that you point that your data is not fully "curated" for reporting, but if you can implement SQL logic to clean it up then you can automate almost the full processs, otherwise, you can automate the exporting to Excel, do the clean up work by hand, and automate the sending of the report to the managament guys (DBxtra can also connect to Excel directly and create reports from it).

If you want to do it by hand, you can do an application on any .NET language and look up for a way to connect to MySQL (ADO.NET) and export to Excel (Excel Interop or third party library).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm definitely reading up about dbextra this weekend.